# C++ Win32 GetWindowText buffer capacity

Tags: c++, winapi, text, buffer

I'm learning to write basic Win32 apps in C++ and am trying to pass typed text from one editable textbox to a new window after pressing a button.

[image]

I noticed that the default text buffer capacity for such a transfer is 20 characters in Visual Studio 2019 (I am on 64-bit Windows 10). After I try to pass a string longer than 20 characters, I get an exception thrown.

[image]

I would like to know how to increase that buffer capacity, since eventually I want to be able to pass a filepath into the text input window and open that file.

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//lresult callback prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

//window handles
HWND hMainWindow;
HINSTANCE hMainInstance;

HWND hLblOutput;
HWND hTxtInput;
HWND hButton;

#define IDC_TEXTBOX 1000
#define IDC_BUTTON 1001

//call to winmain - equivalent of main for win32 environments
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("NiceWindowsApp");
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("My Windows Application"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    hMainInstance = wc.hInstance;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
//callback definition
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int offset = 0;
    switch (message) {

    case WM_CREATE:
        hMainWindow = hWnd;
        hTxtInput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT("Type something here"),
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT, 50, 50, 400, 25, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);
        hButton = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Press Me!"), WS_VISIBLE |   WS_CHILD | WM_COPY | ES_LEFT, 500, 30, 100, 60, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hMainInstance, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON)
        {
            
            //CANNOT HANDLE MORE THAN 20 CHARACTERS!!!
            std::string input;
            GetWindowTextA(hTxtInput, reinterpret_cast<char*> ((char*)input.c_str()), 400);
    
            ++offset;

            hLblOutput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), input.c_str(), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_READONLY | ES_LEFT, 50, 200 + offset * 26, 800, 25, hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);

        }

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to increase the third parameter in `GetWindowTextA()` to various numbers up to 4000, but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. `c_str()` will return a pointer and that API is writing to that pointer which is dangerous. Better use char array. Also, better use dialog box templates, it will a lot easier

Comment: There is no default buffer size. The buffer is going to be the size **you** are allocating. You aren't allocating any space, but promise that you have room for 400 characters. The behavior of that is undefined. To know how large that buffer should be, call [`GetWindowTextLengthW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw). Also, use `GetWindowTextW` rather than `GetWindowTextA`, and `std::wstring` in place of `std::string`.

Comment: @Asesh There's nothing inherently dangerous about using `c_str`, and it's certainly better to use a resizable object like a `string` instead of a fixed length array. Of course the posted code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

One correct way to do this is:

```cpp
std::wstring text;        
text.resize(GetWindowTextLengthW(hTxtInput));
text.resize(GetWindowTextW(hTxtInput, text.data(), text.size() + 1));
```

Comment: Is the double resize required?

Comment: Thanks. I'll tinker around with everything else suggested in this thread.

Comment: @user20716902, Yes, unless you want possible extra 0 bytes at the end. The documentation describes specific scenarios, but not a bad idea to play it safe in general and not have to remember the specifics.

Comment: Resizing twice isn't strictly required. `text.resize(GetWindowTextLengthW(hTxtInput)); GetWindowTextW(hTxtInput, text.data(), text.size() + 1);` is sufficient.

Comment: That assumes that you always know exactly how much text is going to be returned, but it might be less. I would definitely recommend the second resize for correctness. But you are right about the required size. I was misremembering the rules from before c++11 – adapted the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Solved as per the below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>



//lresult callback prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);



//window handles
HWND hMainWindow;
HINSTANCE hMainInstance;

HWND hLblOutput;
HWND hTxtInput;
HWND hButton;

CHAR s_text_1[]{ "Some text.." };
CHAR s_text_2[]{ 0 };


#define IDC_TEXTBOX 1000
#define IDC_BUTTON 1001




//call to winmain - equivalent of main for win32 environments
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{


    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("NiceWindowsApp");
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("My Windows Application"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    hMainInstance = wc.hInstance;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
//callback definition
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int offset = 0;
    switch (message) {

    case WM_CREATE:
        hMainWindow = hWnd;
        hTxtInput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), s_text_1,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT, 50, 50, 400, 25, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);
        hButton = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Press Me!"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WM_COPY | ES_LEFT, 500, 30, 100, 60, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hMainInstance, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON)
        {
            
            //CANNOT HANDLE MORE THAN 20 CHARACTERS!!!
            std::wstring input;
            
            //GetWindowTextW(hTxtInput, reinterpret_cast<char*> ((char*)input.c_str()), 400);
            int lgth = GetWindowTextLength(hTxtInput);
            //GetWindowTextW(hTxtInput, reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*> ((wchar_t*)input.c_str()), lgth);
            //GetWindowTextA(hTxtInput, char[], 400);
            GetWindowText(hTxtInput, s_text_1, 255);
            

            
            ++offset;



            hLblOutput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), s_text_1, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_READONLY | ES_LEFT, 50, 200 + offset * 26, 800, 25, hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);
            SetWindowText(hLblOutput, s_text_1);

            

        }



    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your hints everybody.

EDIT: I now realise that this solution is not technically perfect and can lead to undefined behaviour and/or memory leaks. I'll take the advice presented in the other answers and comments into account and adjust the code accordingly.

EDIT 2.0 (2023.02.04): My most recent code is below. Hopefully it's more robust.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
//last update - 04.02.2023 as per StackOverflow thread recommendations.


//lresult callback prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);



//window handles
HWND hMainWindow;
HINSTANCE hMainInstance;

HWND hLblOutput;
HWND hTxtInput;
HWND hButton;

CHAR s_text_1[]{ "Some text.." };


#define IDC_TEXTBOX 1000
#define IDC_BUTTON 1001




//call to winmain - equivalent of main for win32 environments
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{


    MSG msg = { 0 };
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BACKGROUND);
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("NiceWindowsApp");
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 1;

    hMainWindow = CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("My Windows Application"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    hMainInstance = wc.hInstance;

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
//callback definition
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int offset = 0;
    switch (message) {

    case WM_CREATE:
        hMainWindow = hWnd;
        hTxtInput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), s_text_1,
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_LEFT, 50, 50, 400, 25, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);
        hButton = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Press Me!"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WM_COPY | ES_LEFT, 500, 30, 100, 60, hWnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_BUTTON, hMainInstance, NULL);
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON)
        {
            
            
            std::wstring input;
            
            //resize added as suggested

            input.resize(GetWindowTextLengthW(hTxtInput));  
            GetWindowTextW(hTxtInput, input.data(), input.size() + 1);
            
            ++offset;

            hLblOutput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, TEXT("EDIT"), s_text_1, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_READONLY | ES_LEFT, 50, 200 + offset * 26, 800, 25, hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_TEXTBOX, hMainInstance, NULL);
            SetWindowTextW(hLblOutput, input.data());

        }



    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is still broken if the window text is longer than `"Some text.."`. You only made it harder for the debugger to notice that your code is broken. You are overwriting memory after `s_text_1`, which can have arbitrary bad effects.

Comment: The solution is to this as described in the above answer. **Query** the edit control to see how long the text is. **Resize** your string so that it is large enough to receive the text. **Only** then copy the text to your string.

Comment: I tried it with various combinations longer than 20 characters and it seems to work properly.

Comment: Read up on Undefined Behavior in C++. You'll find that there are cases where the code can be definitely wrong but can appear to work in some circumstances. But the since they're actually wrong, they can often seem to unexpectedly break later due to some seemingly unrelated change. C++ expects you to obey the rules of the language and doesn't catch every possible problem with a clear unavoidable error message.

Comment: @AlexMiroshnychenko `s_text_1` is a **fixed size** array. Its size is not being specified, but it's being initialized with a string literal, so its size is the length of the string + 1 for the null terminator. As such, its size is 12 `char`s max. But, when calling `GetWindowText()`, you are telling the API that `s_text_1` has room to receive 255 `char`s (including a null terminator), but that size is wrong. Any user text more than 11 `char`s in length will **overflow `s_text_1`**. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtexta)...

Comment: @AlexMiroshnychenko ... you have the same problem with the `std::wstring`, only that time the `wstring`'s size is 0 since you are not allocating any space at all for its character data. That is where `wstring::resize()` comes into play. Also, there is no need to use `reinterpret-cast` and C-style casting together. If you want a writable pointer to the `input` string's buffer, use `input.data()` (C++17 and later) or `&input[0]` instead, no casting needed.